# Notifications not showing

Tags: updates, sms, notifications

With the new updates, I can't see any of my notifications on the lock screen. I have to unlock my phone to see anything. It's so inconvienent. How can I change it back or fix it or something???

Comment: By "new updates", did you mean Lollipop? We don't know what was updated if you don't mention it. Also, what phone model (and Android version) are you using?

Answer (score 1):

If you are running Android 5.0 or later go into Settings > Sound & notification > "When device is locked" and set "Show all notification content" (as shown here: https://youtu.be/GNFE-S42wgU?t=46s )

Comment: This is assuming that the update was indeed Lollipop, which is the biggest possibility, but no 100% certain until the OP clarify it...

Comment: Correct, edited the answer